# How to fire ErrorBoundary on async method in Blazor

Tags: error-handling, blazor

I have use ErrorBoundary in MainLayout.razor page but it doesn't work for async methods.
without async method it will fire ErrorBoundary inbuilt component so Can any one have any idea about how to use ErrorBoundary in async method in blazor?

```
 Mainlayout.razor

<ErrorBoundary @ref="errorBoundary">
     <ChildContent>
        @Body
     </ChildContent>
     <ErrorContent>
           Error Message
     </ErrorContent>
</ErrorBoundary>
```

Game.razor page

```
@code{
       ErrorBoundary errorBoundary;
       protected override void OnParametersSet()
       {
             errorBoundary?.Recover();
       }

       public async void OutRange()
       {
             int[] a = new int[5];
             Console.WriteLine(a[6]);
       }
}
```

When this OutRange() function is called then whole behavior is being stoped. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: They do work for async methods. Please show the code.

Comment: i have update my code here can you provide a solution @BrianParker

Comment: Its works perfectly fine for async Task so one option is that we have to use async Task for Method

Comment: `async void` should only be used on fire and forget methods. ValueTask is another option depending on where its getting called from, its a little faster.